# How to write SQL Query with an optional paramter?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services to make a few reports.
I have a few reports where filters are optional.

For example .. Imagine you have a report of books. The end user has the option to specify (or filter by) none, one, or many authors.

I do not believe I  can put an IF { } statement into my query?

If there a suggest or best way to do this in SQL Server Reporting Services?
thanks!

Comment: There are quite many ways to solve this matter but you really should provide some actual example.

Comment: Why can't you put an IF statement into your query?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5187649/243925 ??

Comment: Tony - you are right it is a duplicate. However I tagged this in the Reporting Services as there may be a built in way to handle it.

Comment: Updated my answer as I didn't realise it was for SSRS until the tag was changed... same answer stillapplies, you just need to do something in SSRS to use it... see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this anywhere you want a condition..

```
WHERE ((:param0 IS NULL) OR (column_name0 = :value0)) 
  AND ((:value1 IS NULL) OR (column_name1 = :value1)) 
  AND...
```

Pass Null into the parameter if you don't want to use it.

In SSRS, you'll need to set the paremeters as NULL by default in SSRS... [see here for more detail](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/egiardina/archive/2007/06/26/sql-server-reporting-services-optional-parameters.aspx)

Comment: "Pass Null into the parameter if you don't want to use it" -- can also create the procedure with the parameters defaulting to `NULL`. Can also use a 'magic' default value other than `NULL` ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen: +1, yup that too :) - though be careful, you could accidentally get all rows returned :/

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to tell without seeing the whole procedure that you've written, but you can have multiple values in your `WHERE` clause by using the statement `IN`,

eg:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   BOOKS 
WHERE
   AUTHOR IN ('AUTHOR1', 'AUTHOR2', ...)
```

You can provide everything in the author list in a single (type eg `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `TEXT`) parameter if you like by using a set delimiter and then using a split function in your `WHERE` clause. Obviously if this parameter is empty or `NULL` the procedure would return all books.

There may be other approaches but this one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to push the requested authors into a staging table and query from that.

```
Select ...
From books
Where Exists    (   
                Select 1
                From author_staging As S
                Where S.author = books.author
                )
```

If the desired behavior was to return all books if no authors were selected, then you could do:

```
Select ...
From books
Where Exists    (   
                Select 1
                From author_staging As S
                Where S.author = books.author
                Union All
                Select 1
                From ( Select 1 As Value ) As Z
                Where Not Exists    (
                                    Select 1
                                    From author_staging As S1
                                    )
                )
```

Or another form:

```
Select ...
From books
Where Exists    (   
                Select 1
                From author_staging As S
                Where S.author = books.author
                )
    Or Not Exists   (
                    Select 1
                    From author_staging As S1
                    )
```